# Passing enums to a function

Tags: typescript

I need to write a function that takes as its arguments an enum and a function that accepts it as an argument. Something like:

```
  enum E1 {
    VALUE11 = "value1.1",
    VALUE12 = "value1.2"
  }
  enum E2 {
    VALUE21 = "value2.1",
    VALUE22 = "value2.2"
  }

  const f1 = (e: E1) => e;

  const f2 = (e: E2) => e.toUpperCase();

  const ff = (e: E1 | E2, f: (e: E1 | E2) => typeof e) => f(e);

  console.log(ff(E1.VALUE11, f1)); // type error for f1
  console.log(ff(E2.VALUE21, f2)); // type error for f2
```

Can it be written in a more generic way (avoiding using `any`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that this approach allows `ff` to return `E1 | E2 | string`, the latter to make `f2` work.

```
const ff = <Type extends E1 | E2>(e: Type, f: (arg: Type) => Type | string) => f(e);
```

**Update**

As OP mention in comment, `T extends enum` would be nice, but that is still in [issue-stage](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611).

Comment: Nice. You still need to pass E1 and E2, would not work for arbitrary enum

Comment: Thanks @GRZa. There's an ongoing issue on this, hopefully it will come to some solution soon: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30611 BR